# Difference between spark.sql() and cursor.execute in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

what is difference in working of both. as i am getting result in executing below command.

```
spark.sql("select * from MetadataTable").show()
```

but when i am trying to run `cursor.execute("select * from MetadataTable")`, it is showing me error

> "metadatatable" does not exist

what should I do access table "metadatatable" by `cursor.execute`?

Comment: what is `cursor` ?

Comment: pg_hook = PostgresHook(postgres_conn_id="ingestion_db", schema="ingestiondb")
connection = pg_hook.get_conn()
cursor = connection.cursor()

Comment: Connection.cursor is not spark

Answer (score 0):

At a glance, spark.sql is the spark way to use SQL to work with your data.

Cursor.execute does not appear to be spark code.

Perhaps it is python code for interaction with a database.

You could share the documentation if this seems wrong, but probably reviewing the documentation should explain what it is.

Answer (score 0):

cursor.execute() is part of the pyodbc package ([ref here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#executesql-parameters)).This package is used to remotely access sql servers with an ODBC connection.

Based on the original spark code, it appears that you are looking to read a table in the spark context called MetadataTable. You will have to figure out where this table lives in the spark context, but I assume that this table is not remote, and therefor will not require pyodbc.

Answer (score 0):

**cursor.execute():** This method executes the given database operation from  remotely access sql servers.

**spark.sql() :**  is a module in PySpark that is used to perform SQL-like operations on the data stored in memory